# Creating a named range based on EXACT string values in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that goes through values that I have in column C. When it finds the word "Search", the code creates a named range called "Search" for columns D to F.

```
Dim featuresRng As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim counter As Long
Dim cell As Range

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Features")
Set featuresRng = sht.Range(sht.Range("C1"), sht.Range("C" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'dynamically set the range of features
counter = 0 'this counter will help us avoid Union(Nothing, some range), which would give an error

For Each cell In featuresRng 'loop through the range of features
    If cell.Value = "Query Builder" Then
        counter = counter + 1
        If counter = 1 Then
            Set rng = sht.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3))
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, sht.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3))) 'build the range
        End If
    End If
Next cell
Debug.Print rng.Address
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "QuBuild", rng
```

However, whilst it appears fine on the Name Manager, when I use VBA to transition the range into a table in word, it seems to paste ALL values where the word "Search" is in column C. 
Note, in column C I have a variety of cell values such as "Reporting", "Search", "Search and Filter", "Search and Analyse" etc. So, the range that is pasted into word appears to include the rows from the "Search and.." cells too.

This is the code I am using to export to a bookmarked position in word...

```
  On Error Resume Next

      Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

      If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Make MS Word Visible and Active
  WordApp.Visible = True
  WordApp.Activate

'Create a New Document
  Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("Doc1") 

'Copy Excel Table Range

     'Copy and Paste Search into MS Word
        If DoesNameRangeExist("Search") = True Then
      Search.Copy
  myDoc.Bookmarks("Search").Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False
End If
```

Any help is, as always, much much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issues observed in the code

1. for opening New document in the word try something like `Set myDoc = Wordapp.Documents.Add'
2. Don't know what is  `DoesNameRangeExist`, if is some sub routine the that is not produced in the code
3. The name of the NamedRange in question is "QuBuild" but you have used Name "Search"

Try following modification to make it work (as tested by me to work).

Add reference to Microsoft Word XX Object Library

in declaration section

```
Dim Nm As Name
Dim Wordapp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc  As Word.Document
```

Finally in last section

```
Set myDoc = Wordapp.Documents.Add

    For Each Nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If Nm.Name = "QuBuild" Then
        Nm.RefersToRange.Copy
        Debug.Print Nm.RefersToRange.Address
        myDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Search", myDoc.Range
        myDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
        Exit For
        End If
    Next Nm
```

Edit: However on trial it was observed that `PasteExcelTable` method is copying all the adjacent rows in between union ranges non-adjacent rows. May refer to the [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43041613/copy-disjointed-cells-from-excel-table-to-word-table-using-vba) however answer in the post does not solve the problem and finally resorted to lengthy way below for correct operation. **Invite & eager to learn more Simple Solutions to directly copy paste Union range from excel into Word from experts.**

Code:

```
Set myDoc = Wordapp.Documents.Add
    Dim RngtoCopy As Range
    Dim xArea As Range, Rw As Range, col As Long, Tbl As Table
    Dim TotalRow As Long

    'If both the section of code are in the same procedure
    'then it is not be necessary to use next loop to find NamedRange
    'And can be directly refer as Rng.Areas  instead of RngtoCopy.Areas
    For Each Nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If Nm.Name = "QuBuild" Then
        Set RngtoCopy = Nm.RefersToRange
        Exit For
        End If
    Next Nm

    Set Tbl = myDoc.Tables.Add(myDoc.Range, 1, 3)
    TotalRow = 0
        For Each xArea In RngtoCopy.Areas
            For Each Rw In xArea.Rows
            TotalRow = TotalRow + 1
            If TotalRow > Tbl.Rows.Count Then Tbl.Rows.Add
            col = 0
                For Each cell In Rw.Columns
                col = col + 1
                Tbl.cell(TotalRow, col).Range.Text = cell.Value
                Next
            Next
        Next
```